# Native Admob Ads integration

Tags: android, admob, ads, native-ads

I need to use native admob ads in my android application and i got sample app from github
 https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

and run successfully and ads visible.

i created banner and Interstitial ads key and replace one by one but ads not visible and got message as "Failed to load Native Ads: 0" as a Toast.

Can u guide me for right path.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29586073/google-banner-ads-failed-to-load-ad-0

Comment: @AmodGokhale , Do not post irrelevant comments if you do not understand the question

Comment: @BhavikMehta - can you explain why this comment is irrelevant. Its not a answer, Comments are for others as guidance. If you feel there is better answer can you answer this question?